# Why is $\det \Phi =\det \Psi =1 $.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, definition

I found this in *Partial Differential Equations, Evans*, page 627.

I would to like understand why Evans claims that $\det \Phi =\det \Psi=1$. Here, $y_i=x_i:= \Phi^{i}$, $i=1,\ldots,n-1$ and $y_n=x_n -\gamma(x_1, \ldots,x_{n-1})$ ($y=\Phi(x)$).

The inverse transform is similarly defined: $x_i=y_i$ when $i=1,\ldots,n-1$, $x_n=y_n + \gamma(x_1, \ldots,x_{n-1}) $.($x=\Psi(y)$). The function $\gamma  :\mathbb R^{n-1}\to \mathbb R$ is of class $C^2$. The book says  $\det \Phi =\det \Psi=1$.

I tried with $n=2$ as follows:
The transformation $T$ defined on $\mathbb R^2$ by $y_1=x_1$ and $y_2=x_2 -\gamma(x_1)$. I chose the basis $e_1,e_2$ of $R^2$ so $[T(e_1)]_{e_1,e_2}=(1,-\gamma(1))$ and $[T(e_2)]_{e_1,e_2}=(0,1-\gamma(0))$, so when I do the determinant of the matrix that represents $T$ I obtain $1-\gamma(0)$, which is different from $1$.

Please, can somebody help me or give me some hint? Thank you. Here is a poor quality screenshot (sorry):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzRqf.jpg

Comment: If you're going to post an image, please crop it so that $70\%$ isn't blank white space.

Comment: than you, but please how to do that, im not expert in this

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3768367/show-that-det-phi-1 You shouldn't ask the same question twice

Comment: Does this answer your question? [show that $\det \Phi =1$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3768367/show-that-det-phi-1)

Comment: well anybody answer me before, so i put in the picture where i found this because maybe somebody can help me with this

Comment: Yes, I saw that this question has more information (e.g. the picture). What you should do is edit the previous post, not make a new one. Also please see integrand's comment before you update the older one

Comment: thank you Calvin Khor, i will edit the other question  or delete .

Comment: I think you misunderstood me, this is the question that should have been deleted. The other one didn't have a -1 vote which would make it more likely that people care

Comment: yes you right, well i thought the other one is forget and this is most recently, i stay with this a litle more, thank you again

Comment: OK. Editing a post will bring it to the front page. So your older Question would get more attention again if you added the picture to it. This is also why you should make the picture better before editing, you want to show people the question only when it is as good as you can make it.

Comment: thank you so much Calvin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not clear what the determinant of $\Phi(x)\in\mathbb R^n$ should be. Instead it should be that the determinant of $\nabla\Phi(x) \in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$ is $1$. This has been corrected in the Second Edition: [image]

The reason the determinant of $\nabla\Phi$ is identically one is because the matrix is lower triangular with all diagonal entries equal to 1. I write it out below in the special case of dimension 2:
$$ \nabla\Phi(x) = \begin{pmatrix}\partial \Phi_1/\partial x_1 & \partial \Phi_1/\partial x_2 \\ \partial \Phi_2/\partial x_1 & \partial \Phi_2/\partial x_2 \end{pmatrix}(x) = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ -\gamma'(x_1) & 1\end{pmatrix}.$$

The determinant of the gradient of the inverse map follows.

Comment: terrific Calvin Khor, thank you so much

Comment: @weymarandres you're welcome